# Tabulate with vertical headers or concatenate string list with numpy array and tabulate

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, numpy

I am surprised I have searched so much but didn't find anything. I have a Python list of strings, size 15, like

```
['aa',

 'ab',

 'ac',

 'ad',

...]
```

And I have a numpy array of `size (15,2)`, which I want to concatenate onto this and print as a table using tabulate from the tabulate package or any other way to print a table. I tried lots of ways to concatenate them such as
`print(tabulate((a, result.T)))`
but nothing is working yet. The output should be something like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.c_`:

```
import numpy as np
import tabulate
from string import ascii_lowercase as abc

a = ["a" + j for j in abc[:4]]
b = np.random.randint(0,10,(2,4))

print(tabulate.tabulate(np.c_[a,b.T],tablefmt="fancy_grid"))
# ╒════╤═══╤═══╕
# │ aa │ 2 │ 7 │
# ├────┼───┼───┤
# │ ab │ 4 │ 8 │
# ├────┼───┼───┤
# │ ac │ 4 │ 1 │
# ├────┼───┼───┤
# │ ad │ 2 │ 4 │
# ╘════╧═══╧═══╛
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```py
import numpy as np

# list_ = this is list of strings
# arr = array form of list_
# mainArr = numpy array of size (15,2)

arr = np.asarray(list_).reshape(15, 1)
mainArr = np.hstack((arr, mainArr))
print(mainArr)
```

Comment: I think you mean hstack since vstack gives an error and we are concatenating horizontally. It does produce what I need without the table format but it's good to always have a second method to confirm. I will probably use the other code below since it uses tabulate and gives better formatting.